# Write an instruction which reads the first byte of its own opcode and stores it into al register

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16

I started studying assembly language and there is a question in my book: Write an instruction which reads the first byte of its own opcode and stores it into al register. I can add two numbers but I can't understand what to do in this question. All I can think of is this:

```
mov al,byte[0100];
```

If someone can help I would really appreciate it. *(P.S. I use DosBox NASM using iapx88.)*

Comment: I guess you could use a label like this `mylabel: mov al, [cs:mylabel]` . That would give you the first byte of the instruction. You'd have to add +1 to mylabel (`[cs:mylabel+1]`to get the opcode as the first byte is the _CS_ segment override.

Comment: If you are in a DOS COM program you can do it without the CS segment and DS are the same

Comment: `0100` in NASM is decimal `100`.  Not octal or hex.  A `.com` executable is loaded at `org 100h`, not `org 100`.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to read the byte at the address the instruction is at. You can cheese it with a label:

```
foo:
mov al,byte ptr [cs:foo+1]
```

I want to say there's another way that doesn't use labels but I can't think of it right now.

Comment: You can use the dollar sign in NASM.

Comment: PC-relative addressing was new in x86-64 machine code, repurposing the shorter (no SIB) of the two 32-bit-mode encodings that meant absolute `[disp32]` to mean `[RIP + rel32]`.  Outside of 64-bit mode, the only way to encode a single instruction that references its own machine code is to hard-code the absolute address (offset) into it, as you're doing.  How you do that in asm source varies, e.g. `$` in NASM/MASM/FASM being the start of the current instruction, or `.` being the same thing in GAS.  (In x86-64 CS/DS segment bases are fixed at 0, so `mov al, [rel $]` is `8a 05 fa ff ff ff`.)

Comment: Or x86-64 `movzx eax, byte [rel $]` reads the first byte of its 2-byte opcode, also position independent.  (Weird to say "first byte of its own opcode" when the opcode is only one byte; 8086 didn't have any 2-byte opcodes.  I wonder if they meant first byte of the whole instruction encoding, in which case you'd be loading the CS prefix.  In a DOS `.com` executable, tiny memory model, you wouldn't need the CS prefix.)